# VueJS 3: How to rerender replaced template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I've a parent child relation. The parent provide a template, meanwhile the child template is only a `<li>`-fragment.

The purpose of the fragment is to ***merge*** into the parent template.

Trys with `slot` or `dynamicComponent` failed. The current code replace parts of the parent template and render the treated template. **But the output ist pure plain text instead *html***.

the **parent component**

```
// Parent/index.ts
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import AbstractFilter from "../AbstractFilter";
import tpl from "./template.tpl";

export default defineComponent({
    name: "filter",
    extends: AbstractFilter,
    data() {
        return {
            currentFilterTemplate: null,
            currentTemplate: null
        }
    },
    render: function() {
         render this.currentTemplate ?? tpl;
    },

    created() {
        this.setFilterGroupName(),
        this.setFilterTemplate()
    },

    mounted() {
        this._setCurrentFilter2Template();
    },

    methods: {
        _setCurrentFilter2Template() {
            const filterContainer = document.querySelector('ul.filters');
            this._mergeDefaultTemplateWithCurrentFilterTemplate();

            // rerender with merged template
        },

        _mergeDefaultTemplateWithCurrentFilterTemplate()
        {
            this.currentTemplate = tpl.replace('<li class="dynamic-filters"></li>', this.currentFilterTemplate);
        },
        setCustomFilterTemplate(template:string)
        {
            this.currentFilterTemplate = template;
        },

        /**
         * //NOTE concrete this method in child component 
         */
        setFilterTemplate() {
            throw new Error('you has to set the filter template')
        }
    }
})
```

the **parent template**

```
// Patent/template.tpl
<ul class="filters"">
    <li class="dynamic-filters"></li>
</ul>
```

The **child component**

```
// Child/index.ts
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import ParentFilter from "../Parent";
import tpl from "./template.tpl";
/
export default defineComponent({
    name: "main-filter",
    extends: ParentFilter,

    methods: {
        setList():void 
        {
            this.hasResults = true,
            this.filterList = {
                "filterA": {
                  "id": "filter_a",
                  "key": "filterA",
                  "name": "Filter A"
                },
                "filterB": {
                   "id": "filter_b",
                   "key": "filterB",
                   "name": "Filter B"
                }
            }
        },
        setFilterTemplate()
        {
            this.setCustomFilterTemplate(tpl);
        }
    }
})
```

the **child template**

```
<li v-for="filter in filterList">
    <div @click="$emit('filterCollection', filter.key)">
        {{ filter.name }}
    </div>
</li>
```

### Questions

- How to render the new template?
- Is there a alternative solution such with `slot` or `dynamic component`?

Comment: It's unknown how template.tpl is parsed in your case. render function should deal with vnodes, i.e. compiled templates. You couldn't process them as strings like  tpl.replace. This currently looks like XY problem, I'd suggest to explain further what you're trying to achieve, and why. It's quite possible this should be implemented with slots as they are for injecting a piece of a template. "Trys with slot or dynamicComponent failed" - what did you try?

Comment: It's all about dynamic filters. The concrete filters always extend from ParentFilter and use the parent template with concrete list items which should implement in the parent template

Comment: Probably should be done with comp wrapping and not just extending. You'd have `<ul class="filters""><slot><li class="dynamic-filters"/></slot></ul>` for parent template, i.e. it uses empty `<li class="dynamic-filters">` when no slot is provided. And in a child it would be `<Parent v-bind="$attrs" ref="parentRef"><li v-for="filter in filterList">...`. You could access parent methods with a ref this way, but you can keep `extends: Parent` at least to inherit prop definitions.